# Mongoose TypeError: Cannot read property 'googleID' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, schema

I am making a to-do app that works for individual users. I can get data to stick into the database without a user ID but when I try to add the google id to the schema and the database a type error is thrown. Something with my mongoose Schema seems to be broken

TodoController.js

```js
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
const keys = require("../configs/keys");
const Todo = require("../models/todo-model")
//Connect to the database
mongoose.connect(keys.mongodb.tododbURL,() => {
    console.log("connected to mongodb server");
});

   

//var data = [{item:"get milk"}, {item:"walk nan"}, {item:"code for a bit"}];
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true });

const authCheck = (req, res, next) =>{
    if(!req.user){
        //executed if user isn't logged in
        res.redirect("/");
    } else {
        //if logged in
        next(); // fires to the next functionS
    }
};


module.exports = function(app){
    
    app.get("/todo", authCheck, function(req, res){
        //Get data from mongoDB andd pass through view
        Todo.find({}, function(err, data){
            if (err) throw err;
            res.render("todo", {todos:data});
        });
        console.log(req.user.googleID)
    });
    

    app.post("/todo", urlencodedParser,function(req, res){
        //get data from view and put it in the database
        var newTodo = Todo({item: req.body, googleID: req.user.googleID}).save(function(err, data){
            if (err) throw err;
            res.json(data);
        })
    });

    app.delete("/todo/:item", function(req, res){
        // delete requested item from the database
        Todo.find({item: req.params.item.replace(/\-/g, " ")}).remove(function(err, data){
            if(err) throw err;
            res.json(data);
        });
        
    });
};
```

req.user.googleID will return something such as 1374979743

todo-model.js

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");


const todoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    todo: String,
    googleID: String 
});

const Todo = mongoose.model("Todo", todoSchema);
module.exports = Todo;
```

```
istening on port 3000
(node:2656) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
connected to mongodb server
connected to mongodb server
TypeError: Cannot read property 'googleID' of undefined
```

Comment: Could you clarify what the exact error is and where it's being encountered?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough, The data i am trying to send to the database wont work.This is fired when i try to send data from the website to a database The error thrown looks like this `istening on port 3000
(node:2656) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
connected to mongodb server
connected to mongodb server
TypeError: Cannot read property 'googleID' of undefined` The last part in particular is what is wrong

Comment: should it be req.body.googleId or req.body.user.googleId ??

Comment: @xan_z re.user.googleID is from the passport session

Comment: console.log your req.body and see if that is indeed coming in your post request.

Comment: I have console.log my req.body and its shows just this `{ item: 'hey' }`

Comment: then it is not coming in your request body - if you are using passport - the console.log your req.user similarly - if it is not there - then the post data is not flowing to your node app.

Comment: my req.user looks like this `{ _id: 5bc8d6932ba6f00f544084ff,
  username: 'Christian Clarke',
  googleID: '102042407434346425462',
  __v: 0 }`

Comment: `var newTodo = Todo({item: req.body, googleID: req.user.googleID})` should be `var newTodo = new Todo({item: req.body, googleID: req.user.googleID})` or `var newTodo = Todo.create({item: req.body, googleID: req.user.googleID})`.

Comment: i have tried that may times but when i but it in curly brackets i get this error returned `TypeError: Cannot read property 'googleID' of undefined`

Comment: ive found the porblem i  think. the body parser isnt lettinf the googleID in so i cant send it to the database and thus throwing out  the undefined error

Comment: I have found of that adding the authCheck lets me use the req.user.googleID, however it doesnt like me listing it like this `Todo({item: req.body, googleID: req.user.googleID}` as it throws this error `events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
ValidationError: Todo validation failed: item: Cast to String failed for value "{ item: 'dddd' }" at path "item"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem, I was calling req.body and not req.body.item. i had to call item since i was now pushing two items to the database It works now though and i realised half way through my CS class to use one database

Answer (score 0):

If `user` is something you send to your API inside your request's body (I made this conclustion because I do not see the usage of `passportjs` in you code snippet) then you receive this error because you use `req.user.googleID` instead of `req.body.user.googleID`. `bodyParser` parses JSON from your HTTP request's body and puts it under `req.body`.

Comment: Hi, i have tried adding `req.body.user.googleID` however it seems to throw the same error

Comment: also i will only be posting from the text box one client side so only the item data will be sent, maybe it is a problem with body parser its self